# AJAX response issue in modal

Tags: ajax

I have an AJAX request to add form fields in a database, but got issues while appending the new entry in my select list.

Here's the HTML

```
<select id="jform_proprietaire" name="jform[proprietaire]">
<option value="8">Hello World</option>
<option value="35">Jon Jon</option>
<option value="9">Jack Jonhson</option>
</select>
```

The Form in modal :

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Ajouter un proprietaire</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" name="adminForm" id="propritaire-form">
         <fieldset class="adminform">
            <div class="resultats"></div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="control-label"><label id="nom-lbl" for="nom" aria-invalid="false">
                        Nom</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="control-label"><label id="prenom-lbl" for="prenom" aria-invalid="false">
                        Prénom</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" value=""></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="control-label"><label id="societe-lbl" for="societe" aria-invalid="false">
                        Société</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="societe" id="societe" value=""></div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="control-label"><label id="email-lbl" for="email" aria-invalid="false">
                        Email</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="controls"><input type="email" name="email" class="validate-email" id="email" value=""></div>
                  </div>


         </fieldset>
         <input type="hidden" name="6f179ffa2a28133151f3cfe1553978e3" value="1">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <a id="enregistrerproprio" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
        jQuery('#enregistrerproprio').click(function(){
                       form=jQuery('#propritaire-form')
                       jQuery('#propritaire-form .resultats').html('<div class=\"progress progress-striped\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 30%;\"></div></div>');
                       jQuery.ajax({
                               type: 'POST',
                               url: 'index.php?option=com_visites&task=ajax.ajouteProprietaire&format=raw',
                               data: form.serializeArray(),  
                               dataType: 'json',
                               success: function(data) { 
                                    jQuery('#propritaire-form .resultats').empty();
                                    if(data.succes==1){
                                            jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                            jQuery('#jform_proprietaire').append('<option selected=\"true\" value=\"'+data.proprietaire.id+'\">'+data.proprietaire.nom+' '+data.proprietaire.prenom+'</option>');

                                    } else {
                                        jQuery('#propritaire-form .resultats').html('<div class=\"alert alert-error\"></div>');
                                        for (i=0;i<data.retour.length;i++){
                                            jQuery('#propritaire-form .resultats .alert').append('<p>'+data.retour[i].message+'</p>')
                                        }
                                    }
                               }
                           });

               })
        })


        })
```

My data is well imported to the database but I have in console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at Object.success (index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&layout=edit&id=344:60)
    at i (jquery.min.js?7c0336fabba01bb5fea27139dbdfd8c1:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?7c0336fabba01bb5fea27139dbdfd8c1:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js?7c0336fabba01bb5fea27139dbdfd8c1:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js?7c0336fabba01bb5fea27139dbdfd8c1:4)
```

For this line :

```
jQuery('#jform_proprietaire').append('<option selected=\"true\" value=\"'+data.proprietaire.id+'\">'+data.proprietaire.nom+' '+data.proprietaire.prenom+'</option>');
```

If someone could help would be great!!

Thanks in advance !

PS : I ommited to show the php ajouteproprietairefunction :

```
class VisitesControllerAjax extends JControllerAdmin
{



    public function ajouteProprietaire(){
        require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_visites/models/propritaire.php';
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $data=$input->getArray(array('nom' => '', 'prenom' => '', 'societe' => '','email' => '', 'telephone' => '', 'mobile' => '','adresse' => '', 'codepostal' => '', 'ville' => '', 'notes' => ''));
        $data["state"]=1;
        $model=new VisitesModelPropritaire();
        $reussite=$model->save($data);

        if ($reussite) {
            $db=  JFactory::getDbo();
            $query=$db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('*')
                    ->from('#__visites_proprio')
                     ->where('id='.$db->insertid());
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $proprietaire=$db->loadObject();
           echo json_encode(array('succes'=>1, 'proprietaire'=>$proprietaire));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('succes'=>0, 'retour'=>JFactory::getApplication()->getMessageQueue()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` and share the output.

Comment: data.proprietaire is null, I would guess. Like funcoding says, show us your JSON structure from `data`.

Comment: Here's the console log :
{succes: 1, proprietaire: null}
proprietaire
:
null
succes
:
1

It shouldn't be Null :'(

Comment: ok so quite simply you can't access `data.proprietaire.id` because `data.proprietaire` is null - it's not an object, it has no properties.

Comment: I got that data.proprietaire is null, but why ?
As my db is well fulled the data Object should not be empty ?

Comment: I added the PHP ajouteProprietaire Function that stores the data in base and returns the data.proprietaire data ;-)

Here's the problem I think :
echo json_encode(array('succes'=>1, 'proprietaire'=>$proprietaire));
That doesn't return anything

Comment: well from that it seems obvious that $db->loadObject() must be returning null. Trace that back in the code and we get to the query. I'd guess that returns no results. In that case the culprit is generally the WHERE clause. I see that you're matching on $db->insertid(). Does $db->insertid() return a value? I have to say it's hard to see how it would. $db is only created a couple of lines earlier and has not been used to insert anything. Without being able to run the code and debug the variables, that's my best guess. Obviously you can go and verify it.

Comment: Please don't edit something like *"Solved"* into your answer. Instead, accept the answer you find most useful by clicking the check-mark next to it. This will properly mark the question as solved on a system level. (In your case, you'll have to wait a bit until that's possible.)

Comment: Thanks ADyson that was the right point ;-) I solved it by changing the select on the email field since I have it in the previous $data object. Ok Baum mit Augen I'll do that ;-)

Comment: let's hope that email must be unique in your table? And also it looks like the code could be vulnerable to injection attacks that way. Is there some way, using your DB code library, to parameterise your queries? I don't know which library you've used, but I imagine it must find a way to do that, or otherwise protect your data.

Comment: That code part is only accessible for admin loged user, all other classes are protected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution....

In the latest version of MySql the Last Insert ID isn't working very well.
So I changed my function to check on the email field since It's Unique for each user, Here's the updated code :

```
if ($reussite) {
            $db=  JFactory::getDbo();
            $query=$db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('*');
            $query->from('#__visites_proprio');
            $query->where('email = \''.$data['email'].'\'');
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $proprietaire=$db->loadObject();

           echo json_encode(array('succes'=>1, 'proprietaire'=>$proprietaire));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('succes'=>0, 'retour'=>JFactory::getApplication()->getMessageQueue()));
        }
```